# PHP. Передача данных из неординарных тегов

Tags: php, post, request

Могу ли я передать данные находящиеся между тегами `<h1></h1>` придав имя =>

```
<h1 name = "name_it">EVGENIY</h1>
```

И послать `$_POST["name_it"];` , если да, то как поймать в другом файле, если поле внутри `<form action="test_req.php" method="POST">` ?

Comment: Можешь конечно. Поймай через глобальный массив $_POST. Правда h1 не уйдет туда, если ему только присвоить имя.

Comment: Дублируй в скрытом поле значение

Comment: У элементов не относящиеся к `input`, сможете отправить такие данные, если поместите их в `input`, иначе собирайте через `js` в `FormData` и отправляйте.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант
1) ловите js событие "on submit"
2) пробегаетесь по h1 и т.д. и для каждого формируете hidden input с нужными данными
3) дальше submit идет своим чередом, посылая данные формы как обычно